# Cannot seem to write a file in new Cross Platform project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, streamwriter

I created a new Web App in Visual Studio 2015.  I am writing a method that includes writing some data to a csv file.  However the following code, on the streamwriter line produces the error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.IO.Stream'    DecisionMaking.DNX Core 5.0

```
string fname = "D:\\Programs\\Logins\\test.csv";
 using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fname)){
   //Loop here and write to file
 }
```

I have the System.IO package in my DNX 5.0 references.  And the StreamWriter class does have a string [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b(v=vs.110).aspx).  I am using the same code I had in an older mvc 4 project. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute `fname` with `fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);`
Look for the MSDN Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string fileName = "D:\\Programs\\Logins\\test.csv";
fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    //Write to file
}
```

Comment: That works if I use that constructor with the FileStream.  Just don't understand why the constructor I was using no longer works.  It seems to still be a valid constructor but doesn't work in the new projects.